# writing for loop variables to a single line of a file in python

Tags: python

Suppose that I have a list X, and its contents to a single line of a file, i.e.

```
for var in X:
   if var <some conditions>:
         outfile.write("   "+var)
```

How can I do this so that each iteration of the loop is not written to a new line in the output file, i.e.

```
var1  var2  var3
```

rather than

```
var1
var2
var3
```

in outfile. I know this can be done with a print statement as print x, I can't find the equivalent for write.

Comment: It will write to the same line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless your vars already contain trailing linebreaks you won't get multiple lines in your file.

However, you can simply strip off any trailing whitespace using [`rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip):

```
outfile.write("   " + var.rstrip())
```

An even better solution would be creating a list with the items and [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)ing it. Or simply pass a generator expression to the `join()` call:

```
outfile.write('   '.join(var for var in x if condition(var)))
```

The more explicit version would be this:

```
results = []
for var in x:
    if condition(var):
        results.append(var)
outfile.write('   '.join(results))
```

Comment: This would result in: `*  var1  var2  var3`, I don't think that's what OP want.(Ignore the *)

Comment: Thanks - embedding the condition in the join command saves me the need to have the for loop to begin with.

Comment: Exactly. If `condition(x)` is actually a function (and not just e.g. `var > 5`) in your case you could even use `'   '.join(filter(condition, x))`

Comment: Are you sure? Is it faster even for large datasets? I know that "small" generator expressions are more expensive than list comprehensions of the same size, but I assume that to change when the number of items grows.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to ThiefMaster's excellent answer, the `print` function in Python3 allows you to specify a file object and an end.

```
vars = ['one','two','three']

with open("path/to/outfile","w") as outfile:
    for i, entry in enumerate(vars):
        if not condition(var):
            continue
        if i == len(vars):
            _end = ''
        else:
            _end = '    '
        print(entry, end=_end, file=outfile)
```

However using `str.join` is probable easier.

```
vars = ['one','two','three']
with open("path/to/outfile","w") as outfile:
    output_string = '    '.join(map(str.strip, [var for var in vars if condition(var)]))
    print(output_string, end='', file=outfile)
    # or outfile.write(output_string)
```